# Messaging for web component is not visible on Digital Experience Site

Tags: salesforce, messaging, salesforce-service-cloud

I was configuring messaging for web for my digital experience site in scratch org with routing type (queue/flow). I set up everything as per [salesforce help page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reimagine_miaw.htm&type=5).

After publishing the digital experience site, it won't show component on page.

In console, it shows this error:

> Unable to load Embedded Messaging configuration

I have added CORS, Trusted sites. I retested the setup twice.
I have tried to show messaging component on VF page too but component is not visible.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm equally seeing this error in the browser console as well. I get two different errors:
* Error: Failed to retrieve Business Hours data.
* Error: Unable to load Embedded Messaging configuration.